# Why will my map work on one page but not the other

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So I have a Google map set up within a CodeIgniter framework. I have a view in maps button that takes me to the map and that map loads fine, with all the markers and everything. What I am trying to accomplish is to take the basic map from that page and bring it to another page and make it smaller. Sounds simple right!! Well when I paste the code into the new page I get all these error messages from firebug. I am guessing that the other JavaScript that is running on the page is causing these errors but I am not sure. I have pasted the code below...

<---------this code works fine on first page so i just want to copy and paste into new page----------->

```
<div class="domtab">
        <?php
        echo '<div class="large-box"; style="float:left; margin: 0.5cm 1cm 0.5cm 1cm; padding: 1em";>';
        ?>
        <div class="domtab">
        <link href="/intelligencegraph/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
        <link href="/intelligencegraph/resources/css/developer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
        <link href="/intelligencegraph/resources/css/thickbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
        <link href="/intelligencegraph/resources/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/intelligencegraph/resources/uploads/entity_icons" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCy38HO--LhhK-BS1WqIDrHXyFU9ljaRT4&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        <script type="text/javascript">                   
  // This loads the map, 
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $node_address?>);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    // Adding a marker, to map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng, 
      map: map
      });        
  }



</script>
<body onload="initialize()">
<!-- Size Of map-->
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;"></div> 
        </div>  

        </div>
    </div>
```

<----------this is the code that I think is interferring with it--------->

```
<br style="clear: both;" /> 
<a onclick="document.getElementById('graphdb-viz').style.display = 'block'">View Visualization</a>

<div style="display: none" id="graphdb-viz">
    <iframe src="/intelligencegraph/viz/graph.jsp?nodeid=<?php echo $node_id ?>&database=<?php echo $database ?>" height="650" width="950"></iframe>
</div>


<a onclick="document.getElementById('graphdb-viz2').style.display = 'block'">View Alternative Visualization</a>

<div id="graphdb-viz2" style="height: 650px; width:950px; display: none" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="/intelligencegraph/resources/flash/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // For version detection, set to min. required Flash Player version, or 0 (or 0.0.0), for no version detection. 
            var swfVersionStr = "10.2.0";
            // To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string. 
            var xiSwfUrlStr = "playerProductInstall.swf";
            var flashvars = {nodeid:<?php echo $node_id; ?>,database:'<?php echo $database; ?>'};
            var params = {};
            params.quality = "high";
            params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
            params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
            params.allowfullscreen = "true";
            var attributes = {};
            attributes.id = "GraphDBVis";
            attributes.name = "GraphDBVis";
            attributes.align = "middle";
            swfobject.embedSWF(
                "/intelligencegraph/resources/flash/GraphDBVis.swf", "flashContent", 
                "100%", "100%", 
                swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
                flashvars, params, attributes);
            // JavaScript enabled so display the flashContent div in case it is not replaced with a swf object.
            swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");
        </script>
        <!-- SWFObject's dynamic embed method replaces this alternative HTML content with Flash content when enough 
             JavaScript and Flash plug-in support is available. The div is initially hidden so that it doesn't show
             when JavaScript is disabled.
        -->
        <div id="flashContent" style="height: 2000px; width:2000px" >
        </div>


</div>
```

<---------here are all the errors messages--------->

```
//"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8091/resources/js/ckeditor/ckeditor_basic.js"

ckeditor_basic.js

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8091/resources/js/jquery.js"

jquery.js

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8091/resources/js/jquery-ui.js"

jquery-ui.js

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8091/resources/js/thickbox.js"

thickbox.js

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8091/intelligencegraph/resources/uploads/entity_icons/"

/intel..._icons/

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8091/resources/js/jquery-ui.js"

jquery-ui.js

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8091/resources/js/thickbox.js"

thickbox.js

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8091/intelligencegraph/resources/uploads/entity_icons/"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.layout.js?2.6.0"

d3.lay...s?2.6.0

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.geom.js?2.6.0"
```

Why am I getting them on this page but not the other if everything is the same?

Comment: seems more like a server issue than javascript/google maps

Answer (score 0):

This will not work on any page, you have a double-script-tag here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        <script type="text/javascript">//<--causes a syntax-error, remove this line                
  // This loads the map,
```

Comment: I must have overlooked that when I copied it into the question because it was not in my code.I have a feeling that I have to define something like javascript 1 and Javascript 2.